# Find the highest amount although there are more than one achieving the same amount

Tags: sql, max

I want to find the best customer for each country despite there is one country has two customers the same amount, I want them both to appear.

```
select customerid,firstname,lastname,country, max(total_amt)
from (select invoice.customerid, customer.firstname,lastname, 
sum(invoice.total)total_amt,customer.country
  from invoice
   join customer
   on customer.customerid= invoice.customerid
   group by invoice.customerid,customer.country)t2
group by  country;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select c.*
from (select c.country, c.customerid, c.firstname c.lastname, sum(i.total) as total,
             dense_rank() over (partition by c.country order by sum(i.total) desc) as seqnum
      from customer c join
           invoice i
           on c.customerid = i.customerid
     ) c
where seqnum = 1;
```

Note that I also introduced window functions so the query is easier to write and to read.